# Property declaration craziness iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, properties

I am at my wits end with a property declaration in a iOS class. In my .h file I have the following declaration :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *sessionID;
```

In my .m file I have this code :

```
- (void)setSessionID:(NSString *)aSessionID
{
_sessionID = aSessionID;
// Custom code to set this in a global context
}
```

This is all fine and compiles with no issues. Now I need to have the sessionID return a default value if nothing is set, however the moment I add this line :

```
- (NSString *)sessionID
{
    return _sessionID ? _sessionID : @"defaultSession";
}
```

then the first line in the setSessionID:

```
_sessionID = aSessionID;
```

causes an error with "Use of undeclared function _sessionID. Did you mean aSessionID", I am at my wits end to figure out what is causing it.. I have so many classes with variables and have never seen this before... what is causing this? I restarted Xcode, cleaned out the project and no luck.. If I remove the - (NSString *)sessionID method, then it stops complaining.. but the moment I add the method declaration the Xcode marks it as an error.

Anypointers accepted! :)

Edit: I also noticed, that in this class if I add any property accessor method it complains about the ivar.. e.g. I have another property declared

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *userEmail
```

The moment I add -(NSString *)userEmail, the ivar _userEmail usage above it all becomes undeclared.. :(

Comment: `return _sessionID ?: @"defaultSession"` is simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you override both the setter and getter of a property, the compiler will not automatically synthesize the backing ivar for you. You need to do a manual synthesis,

```
@synthesize sessionID = _sessionID;
```

Comment: You could also just declare the instance variable.